# Couldn autowire. Spring boot

Tags: java, spring

Пытаюсь создать контроллер spring boot. Проект разбит на несколько модулей: dao, entities, services, controllers.

```
    package dao.repository;

    import entities.Movie;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    @Repository
    public interface MovieRepository extends JpaRepository<Movie, Integer> {
        Movie findByTitle(String title);
    }
```

```
    package impl;

    import dao.repository.MovieRepository;
    import entities.Movie;
    import interfaces.MovieCrudService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class MovieCrudServiceImpl implements MovieCrudService {
      @Autowired private MovieRepository movieRepository;

      @Override
      public List<Movie> getAllMovies() {
        return movieRepository.findAll();
      }

      @Override
      public Movie getMovieByID(int id) {
        return movieRepository.findOne(id);
      }

      @Override
      public Movie getMovieByTitle(String title) {
        return movieRepository.findByTitle(title);
      }

      @Override
      public void createMovie(Movie movie) throws Exception {
        movieRepository.saveAndFlush(movie);
      }

      @Override
      public void updateMovie(Movie movie) {
        movieRepository.saveAndFlush(movie);
      }

      @Override
      public void deleteMovie(Movie movie) {
        movieRepository.delete(movie);
      }
    }
```

```
    package cashier;

    import interfaces.MovieCrudService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


    @Controller
    public class ShowMoviesController {

        @Autowired
        private MovieCrudService movieService;

        @RequestMapping(value = { "/showMovies" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String viewPersonList(Model model) {

            model.addAttribute("movies", movieService.getAllMovies());

            return "showMovies";
        }
    }
```

Но при попытке запустить Application:

```
    package app;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"cashier"})
    public class Application {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      }
    }
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
    ***************************
    APPLICATION FAILED TO START
    ***************************

    Description:

    Field movieService in cashier.ShowMoviesController required a bean of type 'interfaces.MovieCrudService' that could not be found.


    Action:

    Consider defining a bean of type 'interfaces.MovieCrudService' in your configuration.
```

Каким образом это можно исправить?

Comment: Добавьте пакет `impl` в `scanBasePackages`, а ещё лучше - вынесите класс `Application` на самый верхний уровень в иерархии пакетов.

Comment: Так и сделал. Теперь сервер запускается, но на страницы не находит

Comment: Ну это уже совсем другая история